# iterative communication between pipes

Tags: c, unix

I want to write a code using pipes. This code is about the rock, scissor, paper game, so I need to ask and receive messages all the time until one of two players score 3. So far, now I have the following code, but I don´t know how to iterate this code, could be with a while iteration?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define READ_END    0    /* index pipe extremo escritura */
#define WRITE_END   1    /* index pipe extremo lectura */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])   
{
    int fd1[2],fd2[2];
    int status, pid;

    pipe(fd1);                 /* comunica ls y grep */

    pid = fork();     

    if(pid == 0)              /* hijo 1*/
    {           
        close(fd1[READ_END]);   /* cerrar extremo no necesario */

        dup2(fd1[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO); 
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
    }
    else                          /* padre */
    { 
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]);    /* extremo no necesario ya */

        pipe(fd2);        /* comunica grep y wc */
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)               /* hijo 2 */
        {
            close(fd2[READ_END]);   /* cerrar extremo no necesario */

            dup2(fd1[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd1[READ_END]);

            dup2(fd2[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);          
            close(fd2[WRITE_END]);

        }
        else /* padre */
        {
            close(fd1[READ_END]);      /* cerrar extremo no necesario */
            close(fd2[WRITE_END]);     /* cerrar extremo no necesario */
        }               
    }

    close(fd2[READ_END]);  /* cerrar extremo que queda abierto en el padre  */

    /* wait para cada hijo */
    wait(&status);  
    wait(&status);

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Why duplicate lines:  `wait(&status);  
    wait(&status);` at bottom?

Comment: One for each kid

Comment: Currently your processes don't do anything related to the game, and all 3 processes will reach the `wait` calls at the end which seems to be wrong. Apparently you have two child processes. If I understand the code correct, the processes are connected with pipes as child1 -fd1-> child2 -fd2-> parent. Please [edit] your question and describe what the processes are supposed to do.

Comment: I know this process is not related to the game, now I am only able to connect the parent with the child, but I want to ask child more than once. I guess I should use a while loop, but I don´t know how